# Given two overlapping arbitrary polygons find best rotation to maximize overlap

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have two arbitrary polygons that may or may not be the same shape, I'm looking for a advice on a simple algorithm that will rotate one of the polygons to minimize the difference between the two. Thanks.

Comment: Is "overlap" the right measure?  If one is much bigger than the other, then it may completely contain it regardless of how much it is rotated.  Also can/should the polygon be scaled or translated as well?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I'm not sure if overlap is the best method, I have tried the mean square error between closest points, which doesn't seem to be correct either. At present scale is not an issue, however I have already accounted for translation, would it be better to do both the translation and rotation at the same time? I don't have a great math background hence trying to put together a more general algorithm, as opposed to going with a mathematical approach.

Comment: OK.  I'm not aware of any "nice" algorithm for this (there may well be one).  Another question: Do both polygons always have the same number of vertices?  If so then I can suggest a "try several rotations and see" approach that uses the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem to optimally match vertices between the 2 polygons.

Comment: The polygons will optimally have the same number of vertices but this will not always be the case, without calculating anything specifically  it seems that brute force approach will be the best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to make them more similar, you could try to minimize the area of the difference between the two polygons. That is, the area of the union of the two, minus, the area of the intersection between them.

An approximation would be to find the two points with maximum distance in each polygon (lets call them 'diameters'), and align those for the two polygons.

For example:

- Polygon A = `[(13, 12); (9, 14); (1,4); (5, 2)]` (a rhombus)

  - Diameter = `[(13, 12); (1,4)]` (length `14.4`)
- Polygon B = `[(14, 11); (8, 17); (3,24); (9, 18)]` (another rhombus)

  - Diameter = `[(14, 11); (3,24)]` (length `17.0`)

Polygon B shifted and rotated so diameters align:

```
[(14.08465297, 12.72310198); (7.439737081, 7.446257009);
 (-0.084652970, 3.276898021); (6.560262919, 8.553742991)]
```

[image: Rhombuses]

Comment: This seems to be a solid approach, thanks, I will implement this and see how it goes.

Comment: There are cases where this goes wrong, e.g. two identical, long, thin triangles can be aligned in two different ways, with about 50% overlap in one case and 100% in the other. You'd have to try both ways to be sure.

Comment: Good point. I didn't even consider this detail due to B being almost symmetrical.